# How to create a private android application download server

Tags: android

What does it take to create a private Android application download server.
Or, at least, is there any documentation about the application loading process for Android?

Comment: please mark an answer correct if you feel it answers your question. This is how you gain reputation point and more privileges

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't really take anything. 
If you want you can put the APK (Android application) files in a public Dropbox if you like and distribute the urls. Similarly you could put the files on a web server. Just think of them as files in the same way you can download pdf files in your Android browser.
You need to have the "unknown sources" box ticked in Settings..Applications

Answer (score 0):

Add file to server and create a download link for that file (plain html) . Add MIME TYPE of APK to your server . Now just browse the link ... And Enjoy !!!